# MacBook RAM Upgrade

Tags: memory, macbook, upgrade

I have a Macbook Late 2006 model; [Specs](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP23))

Will any brand/kind of 2x2GB DDR2 PC2-5300 SO-DIMM 200pin be compatible with this model?

(Like [this RAM](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=220833860815&ssPageName=ADME:X:AAQ:US:1123) for example.)

Are there other considerations I need to be aware of? I have read that upgrading to 4GB of RAM will only get me 3GB. That's fine.

Comment: The link you provided suggests that it will only handle 2GB of RAM max. Are you sure it can handle 4GB? "1GB (2x512MB) of 667MHz DDR2 SDRAM (PC2-5300); supports up to 2GB"

Comment: I read in a forum somewhere that it can go higher, it's just not officially supported by Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum RAM (memory) your system will support is 2GB of DDR2 SDRAM (PC2-5300).  Yes; **any manufacturer's RAM (memory)** will work (assuming its the right type, the product on the link, is).

You will only be able to use 2 of the 4 GB being sold on that link. (as [skub](https://superuser.com/users/70110/skub) said, your system only supports 2 GB.

Where did you read your system can support 3 GB of RAM (memory)?

Comment: I read in a forum somewhere that it can go higher, it's just not officially supported by Apple.

Comment: @JasonBanico: What forum?  Where?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1409899